# Mask Input Fields - Letters and Spaces only

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Setting keyboardType to number restricts the input to number only. Is there a way to restrict inputs in a textfield to letters and space only?

I have tried nativescript-masked-text-field but it is required to declare the number of occurrence of a character. I dont want to do that in a 100-character field.

Are there other options?

Comment: No, it's not possible to show only letters and space on keyboard. But what you can do is, replace the invalid characters (anything other than letter / space) from the input on `textChange` event.

Comment: @Manoj im hesitant to use textChange event because i need it in more than 1 field and it might be too redundant for me.

Comment: That may not be redundant if you just extend the TextField and write it as a Custom Component that listens to `textChange` event to restrict the characters.

Comment: Try [nativescript-masked-text-field](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-masked-text-field) or similar plugins.